# Can you pass a string array as an argument to a constructor?

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm trying to test out some sample code for voting in Solidity. What I wanted to try out is if I am able to pass the names of the candidates (as strings) as arguments to the constructor.

The program deploys, but when I try to put in some sample strings as input, it shows this error:

creation of Voting errored:

```
 Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":3}, value={"types":["string[]"],"values":["Sam"," Andrew"," Ben"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)
```

Is there something wrong with the way I pass the arguments (see screenshot below), or is a string array not supported?

Would very much appreciate any advice! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're currently giving arguments like this:

```
"Sam", "Andrew", "Ben"
```

This works for a constructor like:

```
constructor(string memory name1, string memory name2, string memory name3)
```

But your constructor is:

```
constructor(string[] memory name)
```

To provide input arguments for your constructor, use this format:

```
["Sam", "Andrew", "Ben"]
```

This way, you pass an array with the strings, not separate strings.